# Having multiple ground connections

Tags: audio, noise, ground, ground-loop

When and where should grounds be connected togheter?

I am currently in the process of designing a product as a hobby project. And i find myself getting stuck with (probably) a rather simple question.

Should all different circuit board terminate their ground at a common point? Or can they be interconnected without cousing noise or ground loops?

The circuit is an audio circuit so noise needs to be reduced as much as possible. The interconnects come from the fact that every board gets its own supply line and passes its audio signal to another board(also passing ground)

Here is an illustration of the "problem":
[image: Diagram of ground lines]

Edit: Some more details about this problem:

- The circuit boards are all located in one device(An audio mixer)
- The Signals that pass between them are at Line level audio(the max voltage is about 1.25volt nominal, the source impedance at 470 ohms and the input impedance deviates from 1k to 10k ohms)
- The maximum cable length between boards is around 10 centimeters
- Each circuit board has it's own ground plane which grounds all components on the board. The absolute maximum current draw of a board is around 100mA

Comment: will need more detail – how far are these boards apart, what connects them, what's the kind of audio signal you're exchanging (I guess analog, but is it differential voltage, or single-ended? Current? Line-level or microphone-impedance?)

Answer (score 2):

**Short story**: the external grounding scheme is meaningless without knowing each of the internal grounding schemes and each of the audio signal receiver's method of operating.

**Longer story**:

An understanding of all the audio signal flows is needed to make sense of any external grounding scheme and, depending on how each the various audio receivers process the signal it receives, the external grounding scheme cannot be defined.

So, the internal grounding scheme for each your blocks will also influence the external grounding method hence, a meaningful external grounding diagram is meaningless without knowing the internal grounding within each PCB.

And neither are meaningful without knowing the audio signal transmission processing methods.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease noise, it's better to use a single-point ground between boards, and in the analog frontends of each board.
For signal cables, it is better to use differential output/inputs along twisted cables or coaxial cables.

Unless, there'll be loops between signal and ground, or between bounds.
This makes external electromagnetic waves inducted as noise.

Answer (score 0):

Grounds from different PCBA or other components would ideally be tied together at ONE point on the actual equipment chassis (assuming the chassis is metal). This is sometimes called a star grounding arrangement, and is intended to eliminate common impedence coupling (through shared grounding conductor paths). It's especially important to have components with larger currents not share a conductor with small signal circuits, since larger currents will create a larger voltage signal in the shared grounding conductor, creating large "ground bounce" in the small signal circuits.

When PCBAs communicate small analog signals to another, best practice would be to ground the inter-PCBA signal coax shield at one end only, in order to eliminate potential ground loops. Ground loops can result in external noise being coupled through magnetic field coupling, especially if large power transformers also reside in the assembly.

However, grounding one end of signal wires only is not always possible with off-the-shelf PCBAs or equipment, which may have internal grounding already. Since it's impossible to know what the grounding circuit connectivity internal to any arbitrary PCBA is, there is ultimately no substitute for some experimentation.

Lastly, the star grounding paradigm is best for analog circuits and PCBAs. Digital circuitry has a quite different grounding strategy, called "mesh ground", but that doesn't seem applicable to your case.

Comment: I have added some clarification as to what the signals look like. Maybe this changes things a bit. Following your answer, I think only having ground connection to the PSU from each circuit board might be the best solution. I always thought that in audio equipment having many ground points was actually a good thing

Comment: In audio equipment, more ground points can be worse, since the liklihoof of common impedence coupling and ground loops increases. BTW, the same connection paradigms as grounding also apply to power distribution, since common impedence coupling (sometimes called common mode coupling) can also occur there. Digital logic circuits are different.